# C programming - read 2 different directories in the same line from a text file

Tags: c

I am trying to read two different file directories from a single line in a text file.

eg// under a given.txt file, there are multiple lines of input directory and output directory with a "space" between them in one line

../input1.txt ../output1.txt

../input2.txt ../output2.txt

../input3.txt ../output3.txt

..... etc.
so my goal would be loop reading line by line, fetch input#.txt, manipulate it, then send to output#.txt.

My question is, how to separately read directories in each line with a space between them?

I have tried to google the topic, but all of them are either regarding command prompt argc & argv or reading line by line with one directory in each line.
eg// under a given.txt

../input.txt

../output.txt

but these aren't what I am searching for

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just look for the way to read separate directories for single line, I can work on loop and follow up manipulation on my own. It's my first time asking questions, If anything unclear or inappropriate, please feel free to let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your paths don't contain spaces, you can split the string on the space (using the string manipulation library), which will return two tokens: the first is the read path, and the second is the write path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `fscanf()` function with the following formatted string `"%s %s"`.